# how can i convert surname:name to name:surname?

Tags: python

in these days i'm trying to make a code for to convert surname:name to name:surname in python but it doesn't works -_-

**combo.txt**

```
fiscale:marco
esposito:ronaldo
```

**converter.py**

```
filetxt = open("combo.txt", "r")
for combo in filetxt.readlines():
        combonamesurname = combo.split(":")
        name = combonamesurname[1]
        surname = combonamesurname[0]
        print(name + ":" + surname)
```

i think it's all right but when i run code he makes me this

```
marco:
﻿fiscaleronaldo:
esposito
```

Anyone know how to help me?

Comment: tl;dr: `combonamesurname = combo.rstrip().split(":")`

Comment: use `[::-1]` to reverse a list :

Comment: ryan's method worked, thanks!